# Visual Studio using Solution.Folder

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I created a Folder in my Solution and named it "Brushes". Then I added a ResourceDirectory to that folder and now, whenever i compile, Visual Studio automatically adds `using mySolutionName.Brushes` to MainWindow.g.s and then says that Brushes is not avaiable in the solution.
I don't untderstand why it even adds this code...

I want to store some brushes in that ResourceDictionary which I can then access with

```
  Brush getBrush(string BrushName)
    {
        ResourceDictionary BDef = new ResourceDictionary();
        BDef.Source = new Uri("Brushes/myBrushes.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        return (Brush)BDef[BrushName];
    }
```

Comment: Could you describe your problem more in detail, where did you start, what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio automatically adds a using statement if you tried to use a Resource from the Resource folder you just created.

The compilation error you're getting is probably because you deleted or moved your folder. Try deleting the folder in Visual Studio and in Windows Explorer and add it again.

Comment: I've tried multiple times now, after I deleted and recreated the folder it works but the problem seems to appear again as soon as I open a file in the 2nd project that I have in that solution.

Comment: the file in the second solution I was talking about has the following error:
Invalid value for 'Event'-Property: Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue.

It only shows up, when I open the file and normaly doesnt prevent visual studio from compiling

Comment: As you are adding the resources to your Solution, you need to reference it in all the projects you need to use it, through the "Add References".
If you are using the Resources in only one project in your solution I recommend you to add the Resource files only to the specific project, it is not a good idea to add to your solution as you will need to reference it.

Comment: Looking to your code, you are using "URiKind.Relative". That means it will search for this resource considering your .cs as a starting point. From the location of your .cs file, is there a Brushes/myBrushes.xaml path? 
If you want to get the resource from a single path in all your solution, use "UriKind.Absolute" instead, and change the path to the absolute path of the resource. i.e "C:\users\XXX\Brushes\myBrushes.xaml"